# Any gotchas to using `rsync` in multiple timeout situation

Tags: rsync

I have two machines `A`,`B` on the same low bandwidth network. **`A` wants to copy files to `B` as fast as possible but can get timed out after `t` seconds.** If the transfer process gets timed out, it can be restarted up to 3 times. The average file size is around 50MB with pretty high variance (some files getting close to 1GB).

I'm currently using `scp` with the `-C` compression option and even with `t=300` I'm getting timed out. The process will retry up to 3 times, but will usually get timed out each time because **`scp` will have to start again each time**. Unfortunately increasing past `t=300` isn't an option because of some application logic.

**I'm thinking about using `rsync` instead with the`-P` flag**, which from the man page, seems like will cause `rsync` to keep the progress of previous attempts in a temp file and apply its delta-transfer algorithm to the partial result from last time. **Would you recommend `rsync` over plain `scp` in this situation or are there faster alternatives**? I know `rsync` uses `scp` by default to copy files but I don't think `scp` has  partial progress functionality (I would like to be wrong on that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: `rsync` does not use `scp` to copy files. (It can use `ssh` as a transport, though; perhaps that's what's confusing you?)

If you have a command such as this:

```
scp -pr /source/path/* remotehost:/destination/
```

You can replace it one-for-one with this:

```
rsync -a /source/path/* remotehost:/destination/
```

In this particular instance, I'd optimise away the `*` on the source path like this, and include the `--partial --progress --verbose` flags to improve restartability (and to see what's going on). Notice that I keep the trailing `/` on the source; that's important to `rsync`:

```
rsync -avP /source/path/ remotehost:/destination/
```

You can see what would happen without it doing so by including the `--dry-run` flag.